# insert in database in fragment by button in android studio

Tags: android, database

my app contain **fragment class** , **db class** , **mainactivity class**.......when i click insert button this show "DATA NOT INSERTED",,,,,,I NOT UNDERSTAND......WHERE IS PROBLEM...........THIS IS MY CODE:
Mainactivity class:

```
package ir.hashem.navfragtest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fr1 fragment = new fr1();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment11, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
package ir.hashem.navfragtest;

public class fr1 extends Fragment
{

public fr1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr1, container, false);
    mydb=new database(getActivity());

    btninsert= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btninsert);
    btndelete= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btndelete);
    name= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etjens);

   // id= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            id= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etid);
            Integer isDeleted=mydb.Delete(id.getText().toString());
            if(isDeleted>0)
                Toast.makeText(fr1.this.getActivity(), "DATA DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(fr1.this.getActivity(), "DATA NOT DELETED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String n=name.getText().toString();
            boolean isinserted = mydb.inserdata(n);
            if (isinserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(fr1.this.getActivity(), "DATA INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(fr1.this.getActivity(), "DATA NOT INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
}

.
.
.
```

**Database class**

```
package ir.hashem.navfragtest;

public class database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="market";
public static final String tablename="jens";
public static final String col1="id";
public static final String col2="name";

public database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table jens (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT not null)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jens");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean inserdata(String n)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name",n);
    long result=db.insert("jens", null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAlldata()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select * from jens",null);
    return res;
}
public boolean updateData(String id,String n)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col1,id);
    contentValues.put(col2,n);
    db.update(tablename,contentValues,"id = ?",new String[] {id});
    return true;
}
public Integer Delete(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(tablename,"id = ?",new String[] {id});
}
}
```

Comment: try to get log details of name in  **insertdata(n)** in db class. *ex:Log.d("name",n);*

Answer (score 0):

Use database instance. Add this to your database class.

```
private static database databaseInstance = null;

public static database getInstance(Context context) {

    if (databaseInstance == null) {

        databaseInstance = new database(context);

    }

    return databaseInstance;

}
```

In your fragment class initialize your database variable like this

```
mydb = database.getInstance(getActivity());
```